# Exception declared on ANTLR grammar rule ignored

Tags: exception, antlr, throw

I have a tree parser that's doing semantic analysis on the AST generated by my 
parser.  It has a rule declared as follows:

```
transitionDefinition throws WorkflowStateNotFoundException: /* ... */
```

This compiles just fine and matches the rule syntax at the [ANTLR Wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Grammars)
 but my exception is never 
declared so the Java compiler complains about undeclared exceptions.

[./tool/src/main/antlr3/org/antlr/grammar/v3/ANTLRv3.g](http://github.com/antlr/antlr/blob/master/tool/src/main/antlr3/org/antlr/grammar/v3/ANTLRv3.g) shows that it's building 
a tree (but I'm not actually positive if it's the v2 or v3 grammar that ANTLR 
3.2 is using):

```
throwsSpec
    :   'throws' id ( ',' id )* -> ^('throws' id+)
    ;
```

I know I can make it a runtime exception, but I'd like to use my exception 
hierarchy.  Am I doing something wrong or should that syntax work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue: http://www.antlr.org/jira/browse/ANTLR-100

Unfortunate, as I'm trying to do the same thing.